# tab-shape or round corner background in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, format, headers

In the below screenshot, you can see that each blue group header has a tab-shape or round corner background. Does anyone know to to create it?

[image: Picture]

[Source](http://dashboardspy.wordpress.com/2007/01/25/excel-2007-executive-dashboard-with-new-excel-cube-functions-and-sparklines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a little ingenuity :)

[image]

Here's an example spreadsheet you can download:

> http://www.shoey.com/apps/RoundedCornerSample.xlsx

Comment: I had the same idea, but you did it way better. How did you lock the shape to the cell in the corner?

Comment: Great minds :) I just slid the shape ovrr the cell and they kind of "lock" together... didn't have to do anything special there.